# How a background image can be responsive the easy way?

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to make a background image responsive so it is scaled proportionally from a desktop to a mobile device in the following code?

**CSS**:

```
div.backgroundimage {
  background-image: url('images/image.jpg');
}
```

**HTML**:

```
<div class="backgroundimage"> </div>
```

Please note I have read all similar questions posted but no answer implement proportionally scaling. I mean, with some examples it is possible to scale the width but all replies are missing how to scale the height.

Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean under scaling? Making it fit the perfectly to the screen?

Comment: I mean the process of re-sizing the image according to the screen size.

Comment: plz provide a code example, and or an image of what the effect should look like

Comment: I'll guess what you might think, ist that the box the background is in is not resizing? You can adjust that by checking out the "padding-ratio" hack.

Comment: It's likely that the div also isn't resizing and the question is just poorly worded. If that's the case, you're going to have to include more information, making a div's height and width resize is going to require knowing whether you want it to be the full width/height of the window or of some parent element.

Answer (score 2):

You should be looking into the [`background-size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size) CSS property.

```
background-size: 100%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

The `background-size` property accepts various types of values, one of which is

`background-size: %width %height ;`

If only one value is passed then the other one is set to `auto`.

**Note:-** Please remember that its advisable to decide upon one dimension to be the baseline, and set the other to `auto`. Because if you set both the dimensions then the aspect ratio of the image will *skew* up in most cases.

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: @MohdAbdulMujib This fills up the entire screen but does not scale it proportionally.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of  using the background image property, you could create an image, wich scales to the window's sizes, and put it behind the div:

```
#background-image {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

Comment: I need the image to be called from CSS and not from HTML.

Comment: that would stretch the image without keeping its ratio.
also you can set bottom and right and omit the width and height

Answer (score 0):

You can use the style:

```
background-size: cover;
```

This should keep the aspect ratio (scales proportionally) but also cover the whole area, width and height. If you want to make it cover the whole screen, then you need to make sure it has full width and height as well. It might also be a good idea to center it as well.

See a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mkmcg26a/2/).

This will automatically *fill* the entire width and height proportionally, but this means that some might be cut off on the edges. Also, if the image is smaller than the content it is supposed to fill, than it may look pixelated (see the comment below).

Comment: @Type-Style Sorry. I mistyped.

Comment: background-size: cover does not scale the height of the div.  Take a look here: http://www.w3schools.com/Css/css_rwd_images.asp

Comment: ew, w3schools... and i think you're wrong, but not positive, never used cover myself.

Comment: pro tip avoid w3fools. With the mentioned background -size: cover technique the image will also scale. You just have to make the container itself adjust to ththe width

Comment: I'm not positive that cover will increase the size of the image if it is smaller than the content it is intended to cover.

Comment: @KevinB It does: check it out on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mkmcg26a/3/) (the original image is 128x128)

Comment: well there ya go, this answer solves the problem then. :)

Comment: @KevinB yes it does. thats what "cover" means.

Comment: @glen If this solves your problem, make sure to accept it! :)

Comment: @JonathanLam i'm guessing the div isn't resizing either, thus causing confusion.

Comment: @Jonathan - The image only resize the width, no height.

Comment: @glen It resizes the image so that the height must be larger than or equal to the window height, and the width must be larger than or equal to the window width. It affects only one at a time, which is more often width, but it can also change the height as necessary.

Answer (score -2):

I think you need JavaScript for this:

HTML:

```
<div></div>
```

CSS (for full width):

```
div {
  background: url(https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2015/07/17/06/08/styggkaerret-848532_960_720.jpg) no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

JS (for full width):

```
var ratio = 960 / 634; // width/height of the image
$(window).resize(function () {
  var windowWidth = $(window).width();
  $('div').css('height', windowWidth / ratio)
});
$(window).trigger('resize');
```

### [**CODEPEN (full width)**](http://codepen.io/makshh/pen/pbRvWb)

CSS (for different width):

```
div {
  background: url(https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2015/07/17/06/08/styggkaerret-848532_960_720.jpg) no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  max-width: 500px;
}
```

JS (for different width):

```
var ratio = 960 / 634; // width/height of the image
$(window).resize(function () {
  var windowWidth = $(window).width();
  $('div').css('height', $('div').width() / ratio)
});
$(window).trigger('resize');
```

### [**CODEPEN (different width)**](http://codepen.io/makshh/pen/MeJYrJ)

HTML:

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
  padding-bottom: 66.04%; // height/width*100%
  max-width: 100%; // you can change it for example to 600px;
  height: 0;
  position: relative;
}
.bg {
  background: url(https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2015/07/17/06/08/styggkaerret-848532_960_720.jpg) no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}
```

### [**CODEPEN (padding hack - without JS)**](http://codepen.io/makshh/pen/LZxEdB)

Comment: Could not disagree more! What about 100% dimensions or applying the image to the body?

Comment: What 100% dimensions? And why body? He uses div.

Comment: Allright, I see why you went that way. But you can provide the ratio for the divs via patting-ratio hack. No need for JS

Comment: I don't know this hack very well, I added code for different widths than 100% of the browser window.

Comment: not bad. The background-image needs to stretch into the space its parent got: http://codepen.io/Type-Style/pen/PzWNVm